# Make a GIF play exactly once with Python Wand

Tags: python, python-3.x, gif, animated-gif, wand

I can create an animated GIF like this:

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image() as im:
    while i_need_to_add_more_frames():
        im.sequence.append(Image(blob=get_frame_data(), format='png'))
        with im.sequence[-1] as frame:
            frame.delay = calculate_how_long_this_frame_should_be_visible()
    im.type = 'optimize'
    im.format = 'gif'
    do_something_with(im.make_blob())
```

However, an image created like this loops indefinitely. This time, I want it to loop once, and then stop. I know that I could use `convert`'s `-loop` parameter if I were using the commandline interface. However, I was unable to find how to do this using the Wand API.

*What method should I call, or what field should I set, to make the generated GIF loop exactly once?*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `ctypes` to bind the wand library to the correct C-API method.
Luckily this is straightforward.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Tell Python about the C-API method.
library.MagickSetImageIterations.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t)

with Image() as im:
    while i_need_to_add_more_frames():
        im.sequence.append(Image(blob=get_frame_data(), format='png'))
        with im.sequence[-1] as frame:
            frame.delay = calculate_how_long_this_frame_should_be_visible()
    im.type = 'optimize'
    im.format = 'gif'
    # Set the total iterations of the animation.
    library.MagickSetImageIterations(im.wand, 1)
    do_something_with(im.make_blob())
```